# Extract Date from varchar field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has only 1 large column named `Details`; each record looks similar to this:

```
Record#1: ...ID: <klsdhf89435>  Date: 1 Jun 2011 12:28:14  From: "Yahoo"...     
Record#2: ...Subject: test  Date: Fri, 24 May 2010 13:18:43 -0500 ID: <7532432423>...
Record#3: ...ID: <234321fd>  Date: 14 Jun 2010 12:28:14  From: "Gmail"...
Record#4: ...ID: <12434>  Date: 1 Jun 2011 12:28:14  From: "Yahoo"...
```

I would like the subtract the Date only. So, for those 4 records, I would like to extract:

```
1 Jun 2011 12:28:14
Fri, 24 May 2010 13:18:43 -0500
14 Jun 2010 12:28:14
1 Jun 2011 12:28:14
```

Please note that the double space from before "From" or before "ID" is a new line character which is `Char(10)` in SQL Server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix the schema. That's no way to store database records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Details, LOCATE('Date: ', Details), LOCATE('  From:', Details) - LOCATE('Date:  ', Details))
FROM TABLENAME
```

Consider parsing the date into a new date column when the row is inserted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I've translated this in SQL 2008 and this is what I have:         SELECT substring(details, CharIndex('Date: ', details), CharIndex('  From:', details) - CharIndex('Date:  ', details)) 
FROM TABLENAME                                                                    I get the date but it is followed by other text like this: 
Date: 1 Jul 2010 11:15:22  From: "xxx" <xxxt@yahoo.com>  To: "test2" <natch@gmail.com...  All what i want is just the date part; any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That won't work, since From: isn't always the next field (record 2 has ID: instead).  You could look for that newline as the ending part of your field.

Comment: You are correct. Wondering if there is any other way to solve this issue.